# Allow padding of child element to go out of parent

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
}

#label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#url {
    margin: auto 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-grow: 1;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#clipboard {
    padding: 12px;
    flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span id="label">Label</span>
  <div id="parent">
    <p id="url">Sample URL</p>
    <button id="clipboard">Clipboard Icon</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to allow the padding of the `clipboard button` to flow out of its parent container, so there isn't a space between the `Label` and `Sample URL`. If I use relative positioning to push the `clipboard button` upwards, the icon won't be centered with the `Sample URL` text.

I'm trying to get something like this (no space between the `Label` and `Sample URL`), but with the `clipboard button` aligned to the `Sample URL`

[image]

Comment: FWIW your picture does not match your html and CSS (font, icon etc_)  I also find it is a code smell when you have id's like `#parent` in CSS; use classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the paragraph auto layout so make it a `div` then just give the parent a negative top margin `margin-top: -0.75rem;`.
This can probably be cleaned up a bit overall .

Borders added to show what is where only.

```css
#container * {
  border: dotted red 1px;
}

#container {
  width: 200px;
}

#label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -0.75rem;
  padding: 0;
}

#url {
  margin: auto 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#clipboard {
  padding: 12px;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span id="label">Label</span>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="url">Sample URL</div>
    <button id="clipboard">Clipboard Icon</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had no idea this is what OP was looking for, especially based on the mockup provided -_-

Comment: @Jake I did make some assumptions; and there are several ways to skin this cat - this is simply the smallest that likely works with the excessive CSS and likely "inappropriate" HTML as I noted.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet will be something like what I have below.  Most importantly, you shouldn't try to put your `button` and `<p>` in the same parent div, if you don't really want them aligned with one another.  Code below uses `margin: auto` for the top and bottom margin of the button, vertically centering it in the `#container`.  The height of the container is governed only by the sizes of the two pieces of text, so it will grow and shrink if you change font sizes or paddings or whatever.

```css
#container{
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}

#parent{
  flex: 1;
}

#clipboard{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20px;
  margin: auto 0px;
}

p{
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  
  <div id="parent">
    <span id="label">Label</span>
    <p id="url">Sample URL</p>
  </div>
  <button id="clipboard">Clipboard Icon</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh sorry if I wasn't clear, I actually want the `button` and `p` to be aligned with each other, but I want the padding of the `button` to extend out of their parent container (i.e. the parent's height should ignore the `button`'s padding).